# Desplegar Fullcalendar v5 dentro de un modal por cada fila de una tabla Laravel v9 Bootstrap v5

Tags: laravel-blade, fullcalendar, bootstrap-5

estoy desplegando el resultado de una búsqueda en una tabla.
En cada fila de la tabla despliego ciertos datos y la tengo configurada como botón para desplegar un modal para mostrar la totalidad de los datos incluido un calendario de Fullcalendar v5. El calendario tiene distintos eventos según el elemento de la tabla que estoy desplegando.
El problema es que algunos modales renderizan el calendario y otros no.
Los que lo renderizan lo hacen con error montando los encabezados del día tal como lo muestra la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si avanzo a la semana siguiente el problema desaparece y se despliega correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo HTML Blade a continuación:

```
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm">
                            <tbody>   
                                @foreach ($publicaciones as $publicacion)
                                    <tr>
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#BuscarModal-{{$publicacion->id}}">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-8 col-sm-9">
                                                  <div class="fw-bold">{{ $publicacion->titulo }}</div>
                                                  {{ $publicacion->detalle }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-3">
                                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                                                        <div class="col">
                                                        <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">${{ number_format($publicacion->valor , 0, '.', '.')}}</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col">
                                                        <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">{{ $publicacion->duracion }}&nbsp;min</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around pt-1">
                                                       @if($publicacion->foto1)
                                                            <img src="{{ asset('images/arriendos/'.$publicacion->foto1) }}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width="120" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                                                       @else
                                                            @if($publicacion->foto2)
                                                                <img src="{{ asset('images/arriendos/'.$publicacion->foto2) }}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width="120" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                                                            @else
                                                                <img src="{{ asset('images/arriendos/'.$publicacion->foto3) }}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width="120" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
                                                            @endif
                                                       
                                                       @endif
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    </tr>    
                                        <!-- Modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="BuscarModal-{{$publicacion->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="BuscarModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h3 class="modal-title">{{ $publicacion->titulo }}-{{$publicacion->id}}</h3>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                                        <div class="border">
                                                            
                                                            <h5>{{ $publicacion->detalle }}</h5>
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <div class="row text-center">
                                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                                                    <img src="{{ asset('images/arriendos/'.$publicacion->foto1) }}" width="200" class="rounded mx-auto d-block pb-1" alt="Falta subir foto.">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                                                    <img src="{{ asset('images/arriendos/'.$publicacion->foto2) }}" width="200" class="rounded mx-auto d-block pb-1" alt="Falta subir foto.">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                                                    <img src="{{ asset('images/arriendos/'.$publicacion->foto3) }}" width="200" class="rounded mx-auto d-block pb-1" alt="Falta subir foto.">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <h5>Dirección:&nbsp;{{ $publicacion->direccion }}</h5>
                                                            <h5>Comuna:&nbsp;{{ $publicacion->comuna->name }}</h5>
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <h5>Locacion:&nbsp;{{ $publicacion->locacione->name }}</h5>
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <h5>Accesorios opcionales</h5>
                                                            @foreach ($publicacion->publicados as $publicado)
                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                    <div class="col">
                                                                        <h6>{{ $publicado->name }}</h6>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="col">
                                                                        <h6>Precio:&nbsp;${{ number_format($publicado->valor , 0, '.', '.')}}</h6>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            @endforeach
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <h5>Duración:&nbsp;{{ $publicacion->duracion }}&nbsp;minutos</h5>
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <h5>Precio:&nbsp;${{ number_format($publicacion->valor , 0, '.', '.')}}</h5>
                                                            <hr>
                                                            @if($publicacion->cancelacion == 1)
                                                                <h5>Permite cancelar</h5>
                                                                <h5>Con {{$publicacion->anticipacion}} días de anticipación</h5>
                                                                <h5>Multa {{$publicacion->multa}}% del valor contratado</h5>
                                                            @else
                                                                <h5>No permite cancelación</h5>
                                                            @endif
                                                            <hr>
                                                            <!-- calendario -->
                                                            <div class="row justify-content-center pb-2">
                                                                <div class="border col text-center mb-2">
                                                                    <strong class="align-middle text-center">Disponibilidad</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div> 
                                                            
                                                            <?php 
                                                              $publicacion_id = $publicacion->id;
                                                            ?>
                                                    
                                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                                var publicacion_id = "<?php echo $publicacion_id; ?>";
                                                                var fecha = "<?php echo $fecha; ?>";
                                                            </script>
                                                                    
                                                            <div id="show_buscar_{{$publicacion->id}}" ></div>
                                                            
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">  
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Arrendar</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Y mi javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
        var id_element = "show_buscar_"+publicacion_id;

        var calendarEl = document.getElementById(id_element);
    
        var calendar_buscar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          
          initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
          
          timeZone: 'America/Santiago',
          
          locale:"es",
          
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
          allDaySlot: false,
          headerToolbar: { 
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next',
          },
          titleFormat:{ year: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
          
          slotMinTime: "07:00:00",
          slotMaxTime: "24:00:00",
          
          height: "auto",
          contentHeight: "auto",
          stickyHeaderDates: true,
          initialDate: fecha,
         
          events:{
            url: "/publicaciones/disponibles/"+publicacion_id,
            failure: function() {
              alert('Hubo un error al cargar los eventos!');
            },
          },
         
        });
    
        calendar_buscar.render();
        
      });
```

Tengo el modal dentro del foreach y le paso el id como argumento. Esto funciona correctamente porque en el modal se despliegan correctamente los datos del registro salvo los eventos de Fullcalendar.
Al parecer el problema ocurre con Fullcalendar dentro de un modal en una tabla porque en otras secciones de mi aplicación Fullcalendar se despliega sin problemas.
¿Alguna idea?.